# Comparing two populations

Tags: average, standard-deviation, sampling

I have sampled from two separate populations, and I want to figure out which population is better.

Population 1 has an average score of 84.1 and a standard deviation of 11.8. Population 2 has an average score of 95.8 and a standard deviation of 13.5.

Assume that all samples are independent, and the sample size is 500 for each population.

What is the best way to prove that a random sample from population 2 will result in a greater score (on average) than a random sample from population 1?

What statistic do I need? Confidence interval? Tolerance interval?

Comment: Test for the difference of two means with pooled variance. Google it.